# VS 2012 hangs on loading XAML designer in windows store app project

Tags: windows, windows-8, app-store, microsoft-metro

I am doing Windows App Store project in VS 2012 ultimate.

Since last week, the XAML designer viewer hangs forever whenever I try to create a new Windows App Store project.

However, it works perfectly in WPF, and other projects.

There is no improvement even after VS 2012 Update 1 installation.

What's wrong ?

Comment: In my system, I have a separate "VS Express for Windows 8" for developing store apps and I am using the same eventhough there is a template available for the store app development in VS Ultimate. Did you check that ?

Comment: Do you mean New Project->Visual C#->Windows Stores->Blank App ?